# Is there a way to use theano.function in thread safe mode?

Tags: python, multithreading, machine-learning, parallel-processing, theano

I am newbie in theano. I received an error in my multithreading system:
"assert key not in self.entry_from_key"

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/gof/cmodule.py

In comment: Changing the hash of the key is not allowed during compilation. That is the only cause found that makes the following assert fail.

My code:

```
model_predict = theano.function(inputs=[A, B], 
      outputs=self.classifier.predict(y),givens={x: F, y: D})
```

I read that "function" in theano not thread safe function. So how can I should change my code for use it correctly?

Can I rewrite what theano.function do in simple python code manualy? Or there is another correct way?